# mvvmcross memoryleak in MvxBaseActivityAdapter

Tags: android, memory-leaks, mvvmcross

Now i look at mvvmcross source code and see event handler initializing in MvxBaseActivityAdapter class

```
_eventSource.CreateCalled += EventSourceOnCreateCalled;
        _eventSource.CreateWillBeCalled += EventSourceOnCreateWillBeCalled;
        _eventSource.StartCalled += EventSourceOnStartCalled;
        _eventSource.RestartCalled += EventSourceOnRestartCalled;
        _eventSource.ResumeCalled += EventSourceOnResumeCalled;
        _eventSource.PauseCalled += EventSourceOnPauseCalled;
        _eventSource.StopCalled += EventSourceOnStopCalled;
        _eventSource.DestroyCalled += EventSourceOnDestroyCalled;
        _eventSource.DisposeCalled += EventSourceOnDisposeCalled;
        _eventSource.SaveInstanceStateCalled += EventSourceOnSaveInstanceStateCalled;
        _eventSource.NewIntentCalled += EventSourceOnNewIntentCalled;

        _eventSource.ActivityResultCalled += EventSourceOnActivityResultCalled;
        _eventSource.StartActivityForResultCalled += EventSourceOnStartActivityForResultCalled;
```

But there is no code to clear this event handlers.
So, when i analyze my own app with xamarin profiler, activity is not destroyed because it depends on MvxActivityAdapter and MvxBindingActivityAdapter, and they have references to these Event handlers. 
Is it a bug with mvvmcross or I should clear events manually(but not sure it's possible)?
Thanks

Comment: there must be something else in the dependency graph? Even if "it depends on MvxActivityAdapter" and "MvxActivityAdapter depends on it" the GC can still collect them. Something else must be keeping them in memory... (IMHO)

Comment: Yes, there are some other references. MvxContextWrapper, MvxLayoutInflater.PrimaryFactoryWrapper2, MvxAndroidBindingContext,

Comment: So which one is causing the leak.... (and, also, it might be worth checking there is a leak... objects can hang around without leaking...)